# Discord.js "message.member.roles.cache.has" wont work

Tags: discord.js

Hello I am trying to make a role that can use special commands but my code is not working. I tried to make it find the role by name and it worked perfectly fine, but i dont know why it wont work with id. Here is my code `if(!message.member.roles.cache.has('934008510780440587')) return message.reply("You can't use the command!")`
I always get "You can't use the command!" error even if I have the role. I am using v13 of discord.js.

Comment: nevermind I fixed it